# SPARQL VALUES keyword on strings?

Tags: sparql

I am executing the query below at http://lod.openlinksw.com/sparql.
I want to pull triples for a number of studies all at the same time, using the SPARQL 1.1 VALUES keyword on the org-study-id predicate. This query works when I explicitly state the #string type in the VALUES statement:

```
PREFIX ct: <http://bio2rdf.org/clinicaltrials_vocabulary:>
SELECT * 
WHERE {
  VALUES (?value) {("N01009"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>)
                   ("N01020"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string>)}
 ?nctID ct:org-study-id ?value .
}
```

Is there a way I can shorten the VALUES list by leaving off the #string type specification? This code is what I am looking for but gives a syntax error:

```
VALUES (str(?value)) { ("N01009") ("N01020") }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `^^xsd:string`.

Comment: Given the fact the the question says that the xsd:string datatype must be given, it looks like the end point is not RDF 1.1 but only RDF 1.0.

Answer (score 3):

In RDF 1.1, "plain" strings have type xsd:string, so you could probably just do:

```
VALUES (?value) { ("N01009") ("N01020") }
```

and since there only one value, you don't need the list, so you can just do:

```
VALUES ?value { "N01009" "N01020" }
```

For instance, with Jena's ARQ, we get these results:

```sql
select ?x (datatype(?x) as ?xd) {
  values ?x { "a" }
}
```

```
---------------------------------------------------
| x   | xd                                        |
===================================================
| "a" | <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string> |
---------------------------------------------------
```

But if you need to apply some function to each value (whether it's a string or something else), you can use **bind**:

```
values ?value_ { "N01009" "N01020" }
bind(str(?value_) as ?value)
```

For example:

```sql
select ?x {
  values ?x_ { "a" "b" "c" }
  bind(concat("[",?x_,"]") as ?x)
}
```

```
---------
| x     |
=========
| "[a]" |
| "[b]" |
| "[c]" |
---------
```

Comment: Even in SPARQL for RDF 1.0, `datatype("foo")` is `xsd:string`.